# Слетел перевод верхнего баннера, показываемого незарегистрированным пользователям

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Собственно, вот:

> [image: баннер]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переводы восстановил. Причина слёта не очевидна. Соответствующий баг-репорт уже есть на MSE: [Already translated strings have lost their translations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306091/339911)

Comment: Вроде починилось?

Comment: @NickVolynkin этот баг да, но про все проблемы, описанные на MSE, не знаю.