# Слетела локализация некоторых причин для закрытия

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

> [image]

Связанные топики:

1. [Слетел перевод верхнего баннера, показываемого незарегистрированным
   пользователям](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6807/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F)
2. [Слетел перевод длительности нахождения на сайте](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6815/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5)
3. [Already translated strings have lost their translations](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/306091/already-translated-strings-have-lost-their-translations)

---

**UPDATE**

Всё снова работает, как прежде.